# SSIS Flat File Header Blank Rows

Tags: ssis, header, linefeed

I am trying to add a simple header to a flat file destination that takes up three lines.
However when I add the header info in the flat file destination editor it either a) puts all three lines on one line, or b) if I hit enter after each line enters a blank line as well between the first and second lines (You can see this when you go to properties...header.) When I open up the output txt file in notepad++ the lines are all on three separate rows as well as the two blank lines. If you look at the symbols they are using Line Feed and not Carriage Return Line Feed for the first 4 lines, last line is Carriage Return Line Feed.
This causes issues when I try to import this same file and skip 3 header rows (it should be 3) but sometimes it doesn't work because it should be just skip 1 header row...
Bottom line is something that should be so simple is causing much frustration.
When I am in the header and enter a line "Company XYZ" and then hit enter to enter the second line "Created on date …" hitting the enter, is that a Carriage Return Line Feed or just a line feed? and why is it inserting blank row you can only see in properties? I basically want three separate lines with all Carriage Return Line Feeds. Thanks.

Comment: I don't recommend formatting a delimited file. Nothing but issues will occur. If you want to send formatted data then create a SSRS report and send that in a subscription.

Comment: "When I am in the header.." talk us through how you are creating your flat file and specifying the blank header rows. Check out the properties of your connection manager, if you're using one, and how does it specify the row delimiter.

Comment: The goal is to export data from a single SQL table into a txt file, the txt file does not exist prior to the process. I create a flat file connection, browse to where I want to create the file, supply a name. Then I configure my connection by adding all the columns with corresponding data type, length... This work perfectly fine. The problem is with the flat file destination in the data flow task. When I attempt to add a header with 3 lines it either puts them all on one line or adds spaces between the lines...Company XYZ

Sales.Orders Imported from SQL TSQL2014

Date Columns Not Converted

Comment: if you look in the header it looks like the lines are all on one line, but if you look in the properties and hoofer the mouse of the lines you actually see the blank lines. it seems hitting enter in the header creates a blank line